What's bad with knowing what's good and what's evil?
After Adam and Eve eat of the Tree of Knowledge of Good and Evil, we read:

וַיֹּ֣אמֶר ׀ יְהֹוָ֣ה אֱלֹהִ֗ים הֵ֤ן הָֽאָדָם֙ הָיָה֙ כְּאַחַ֣ד מִמֶּ֔נּוּ לָדַ֖עַת ט֣וֹב וָרָ֑ע


And HaShem Elokim said, “Now that man has become like one of us, knowing good and evil..." [Genesis 3:22]

Why is God unhappy with that?  Isn't it a good thing to know what's good and what's evil?  Isn't the Torah a big lesson on how to tell good from bad?
